# How to allow a function to be call by 2 function separately?

Tags: function, html

I want to allow a function to call by
 - button click
 - pressing of tab key

For example

```
 $("#editable").keydown(function(e){
         if(e.which == 9) 
         {
alert("hey");   
            });
```

Can I use a button to call the function too?

```
$("#save").click(function (e)
```

How to do it?

Comment: Programming Language? Is this Javascript/Actionscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done, you can create a function and the call it on different event handlers:

```
<button id="myButton"> Click Me </button>
<input type="text" id="myText" />
```

JS

```
function myFunction(){
     alert("hi!");
}

$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#myButton").on("click",myFunction);
    $("#myText").on("keydown",function(e){
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
        if (keyCode == 9) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            myFunction();
          } 
    });

});
```

Check out the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/gRC9W/)**